# ASP MVC5 Identity 2.0 Back end and Front End login

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-identity, usermanager

I'm developping a project in which I have a backoffice area (admin area), to configure the system, and a frontoffice area, for the typical user to do his business.

That said, the application needs to have a Backoffice Login and another Frontoffice Login. Each must be separated.

I've developped using, Asp Identity 2.0, a Backoffice and Frontoffice login and registration distinct areas that work well.

For example, one can have a "myuser" username for the backoffice area and a "myuser" username for the frontoffice area, because each is saved in distinct tables.

I've developped a custom Area Authorize to manage this.

My problem is, when a user logs in for example to the Backoffice area, if he goes to the frontoffice area, he's still reported has being logged in...

How can I separate the User.Identity login for each Area?

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: I would suggest using another approach. I think you are mixing two different concepts: Authentication and Authorization. After the user is authenticated, you should check (Authorize) if the user has the rights to access the admin area (you could check if the user has the "admin" role).

Comment: I thought of that too but the client doesn't want to mix the CMS and Application logins... The way I prepared things, the application can use the two different logins but if you login to the CMS, the User.Identity.IsAuthenticated will say for any area that the user is logged in and I can't find a way to check if the login was done on the CMS or Frontoffice... With User roles it's possible, but I would love the see if this can work or not! :) Also tried using different cookies but no such luck...

Comment: By the way, I think it's possible to manage Multiple identities because the System.Security.Claims.ClaimsPrincipal has a list of identities.

Answer (score 0):

Solution adopted:

1) Created Front Office Authorize Attribute and BO Authorize Attribute to Manage the FO / BO Login pages:

```
public class AreaAuthorizeAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    private readonly string area;

    public AreaAuthorizeAttribute(string area)
    {
        this.area = area;
    }

    protected override void HandleUnauthorizedRequest(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
        RouteValueDictionary values;

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(area))
        {
            values = new RouteValueDictionary(new
            {
                Area = area,
                Controller = "Account",
                Action = "Login"
            });
        }
        else
        {
            values = new RouteValueDictionary(new
            {
                Area = "Frontoffice",
                Controller = "Account",
                Action = "Login"
            });
        }

        filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(values);
    }

}
```

Part 2)

To manage the Identities between BO and FO, that is, to get allways via the User.Identity the correct identity depending on the area you are, created this method in Global.asax

```
 protected void Application_AuthenticateRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Request.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            var user = (System.Security.Claims.ClaimsPrincipal)User;

            if (user.Identities.Count() > 1)
            {
                if (HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.ToString().Contains("Frontoffice"))
                {
                    HttpContext.Current.User = new System.Security.Principal.GenericPrincipal(user.Identities.First(), new string[] { "Admin" });
                }
                else
                {
                    HttpContext.Current.User = new System.Security.Principal.GenericPrincipal(user.Identities.ElementAt(1), new string[] { "Admin" });
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Just change the if(Request.IsAuthentifacted) to whatever you want to do when managing the User Identities and BBBBOOOMMMM :)

Comment: Hi Pedro, I am facing a similar situation as you, but I am using the same db table to keep the records for both the users of frontend and backend. In your solution, one thing I dont quite understand, it looks like to me that you update the role of the principal, and assign the updated one to User property in the context, however, what you need to do is to reject admin user logging in through FrontOffice. According to your code, if an admin user logs into the Front Office, he should still be logged in as an admin.

Comment: And in addition, by which mean could the user.Identities have more than one elements? Thanks so much.